# Windows Service Project Maintains Another Executable?

Tags: windows-services, nested

I have one windows service project which is 64 bits, and now I need to have one 32 bits executable which should have the same lifetime of the windows service. Since 64 bit app domain can't load 32 bit dll, so I must launch this 32 bits executable inside the OnStart() function of 64 bits windows service. I was wondering how should I maintain the lifetime of this 32 bits executable? Basically what I have done now is to launch the executable in OnStart() and exit it in OnStop().

But what I am concerned now is, what if this 32 bits executable(process) gets killed or crashed in the middle of the Windows service running? I need to re-launch it. Is there a place or function in the a windows service, where I can monitor other process, and whenever these processes get killed, I can re-launch them? Or I can think of nested windows services, but I can't find any useful material on this topic.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you have a service which relies on an application? This is bad design...what if no user is logged on?

Comment: If they are both services on the other hand, you can use a ServiceController to check the state of the other one, and even start/stop/restart it. This is because all services will be acting as administrative privalige.

Comment: @AdamKing Thanks for your reply. Exactly why is it a bad idea? I remember I read something about launching an executable even without Windows login. And my 32 bits executable doesn't require any interaction. But anyway, it is basically my freedom to decide whether the 32 bits process is an application or Windows service. So I will check the ServiceController too.

Comment: Launching an application without a login can cause problems, there are various issues such as permissions, and login scripts that need to have run first, antivirus concerns etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do personally would be to configure both executables to be Windows Services, that way you can use ServiceController in the manner it is intended in order to make sure your program is running correctly. You can also set one service to be a prerequisite of another.

I wouldn't recommend launching the application from a service, as for this you would be opening up considerably difficulties...

For example, which user would the application be running under?

Going down the ServiceController route and having both parts being services would definitely be my preferred route.

From a design point of view, an executable which is supposed to run all of the time and doesn't require an interface should really be a Windows Service so that the operating system gives correct scheduling, and is able to automatically restart the program should there be a problem.